# ECS scheduled task containerOverrides for entryPoint not working

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a scheduled ECS task in Terraform. When I try to override the container definition for the `entryPoint`, the resulting task does not use the overridden `entryPoint`. However, if I try to override the `command`, it works fine (adds a new command in addition to existing entry point). I cannot find anything in the docs that lead me to believe that there is no support for `entryPoint` overriding but that may be the case?

Below is the code for the Cloudwatch event target in terraform

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "ecs_task" {
  target_id = "run-${var.task_name}-scheduled"
  arn       = "${var.cluster_arn}"
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.ecs_task_event_rule.name}"
  role_arn  = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_event.arn}"

  ecs_target = {
    launch_type = "${var.launch_type}"
    network_configuration = {
      subnets = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
      security_groups = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
    }
    task_count = 1
    task_definition_arn = "${var.task_arn}"
  }

  input = <<DOC
{
  "containerOverrides": [
    {
      "name": "${var.task_name}",
      "entryPoint": ${jsonencode(var.command_overrides)}
    }
  ]
}
DOC
}
```

This creates a new scheduled task on the AWS console, where the input field is the following:

```
{
    "containerOverrides": [
        {
            "name": "my-container-name",
            "entryPoint": [
                "sh",
                "/my_script.sh"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However tasks launched by this rule do not have the entry point override and use the entrypoint defined in the original task definition.

**TLDR**: How can I override the entrypoint for a scheduled task?

Answer (score 5):

As of today, only a [certain number of fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html#options) can be overridden as the scheduled task ultimately uses the `run-task` API. These fields are the following:

- `command`
- `environment`
- `taskRoleArn`
- `cpu`
- `memory`
- `memoryReservation`
- `resourceRequirements`

Container definitions for other fields are not supported, such as `entryPoint`, `portMappings`, and `logConfiguration`.

The solution is to use `command` instead of `entryPoint` in the original task definition, as `command` can be overridden but `entryPoint` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's a misleading proposal to default to using `command` over `entryPoint` in ECS task definitions since `command` will not handle (termination) signals properly, especially when using long lived tasks (e.g. in ECS services), so careful with that! If you really need to have a single task definition with changing commands, I'd rather suggest to use a dedicated entrypoint there (could be simply `['sh', '-c']` for example) and use the dynamic `command` for the (short lived) task runs.